# System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda for expressions with extension methods and methods on the object

Tags: entity-framework, lambda, dynamic-linq

I am using System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression from the System.Linq.Dynamic library to parse the string to an expression on an entity. It is working fine if my expression string contains the public properties on the object but if i define my expression string containing Methods or extension methods on the object I am getting an exception from the parselambda saying "No applicable method '' exists in type '' (at index 0)". 
Can anyone let me know if there is a way to use extension methods or public methods, on the object, in the string expression.

Thanks,
Ajay

Comment: please give code examples. Extension methods probably don't work, regular methods should.